# What would be the ideal data structures for implementing rules like scenario?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Consider the following scenario, where rules defined by ID need to satisfy all conditions .

```
RULES

ID  Attribute1  Operator1  Value1   Attribute2  Operator2  Value1  ... And so on
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1    x            =          10         a         IN        5,10 
2    x            =          20         a         IN        10,15
3    x            =          20         a         IN        25,20
```

The above means `if(x=10) & if(a = 5 or a = 10} & ...,  then ID = 1`

In case of an incoming feed for the format `[x, a, ...]`

```
10, 5, ...
10, 10, ...
20, 20, ...
```

then IDs should be

```
1
1
3
```

**I wish to check if there is a more easy and elegant way than the below solution and which data structure to be used.**

**What are the cons of the data structures & approach used in the below solution? (sure there could be)**

`Assumptions:`

1. The list of attributes is fixed for now but may change.
2. The incoming feed format is fixed.
3. Not on the lines of Java rules implementation.
4. Algorithmic answer is accepted, Java 7 implementation is preferred.

**My solution:**

1. The rule set is organized as `Map<String, List<Criterion>>`, where key is ID and Criterion contains attribute, operator and value as fields.
2. The data is organized as `List<Map<String, String>>`, where key is the attribute (could be x or a etc.) and value as the actual value in the feed.
3. For each entry in `List<Map<String, String>`, do below to find the ID
4. Loop through each of the entries in `Map<String, List<Criterion>>` and invoke the below method. In case `true` is returned, I log the ID, which is the key and break the rule loop & proceeed to next data item.

   ```
   public boolean executeRules(List<Criterion> list,
           Map<String, String> dataItem) {
       boolean fullMatch = true;
       if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)){
           for(Criterion rule : list) {
               switch (rule.getOperator()) {
               case EQUAL_TO: //Similar to EQUAL TO
                   if(!rule.getValue().equals(dataItem.get(rule.getOperand()))){
                       fullMatch = false;
                   }
                   break;
               case IN://Similar to IN
                   List<String> inCriteria = null;
                   if(rule.getValue() != null) {
                       inCriteria = Arrays.asList(((String) rule.getValue()).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                       if(!inCriteria.contains(dataItem.get(rule.getOperand()))){
                           fullMatch = false;
                       }
                   } else {
                       fullMatch = false;
                   }
                   break;


               default:
                   LOG.error("Invalid Operator: " + rule.getOperator());
                   fullMatch = false;
                   break;
               }
               if(!fullMatch) {
                   return false;
               }

           }   
       } else {
           LOG.error("No Rules found");
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

PS: Not a homework; just some research.

Comment: Have you looked at a rules engine such as drools?  Much more flexible than what you're doing here, though not necessarily an appropriate solution for every problem.

Comment: @Taylor Yes though not deeply. I think this is a simple use case & thought not to bring in an engine to complicate. Would love to see this use case could be implemented hands on with Drools.

Comment: You seem to have a simple interpreter algorithm going on, you can complicate this as much as you want but the essence is there. What are your problems/constraints? Have you looked into Logic Programming? This is the kind of thing java doesn't shine on but your solution can be good enough as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you could make use of SmartParam library (http://smartparam.org/). It is designed for such evaluations and is very generic, so you can use if even with properties file as well as with database

Comment: +1 Thanks @JakubK & worth a look. But it looks to be a single contributer project; are you aware of an active community for this project?

Comment: @gsndev I've been few weeks ago at my local JUG and there are 2-3 persons involved in this project, and 2 pretty big companies using it on production.